# Construct an array with from an existing array

Tags: algorithm, heap

Given an array of integers `A[1...n-1]` where `N` is the length of array A. Construct an array `B` such that `B[i] = min(A[i], A[i+1], ..., A[i+K-1])`, where `K` will be given. Array B will have N-K+1 elements.

We can solve the problem using min-heaps Construct min-heap for k elements - O(k). For every next element delete the first element and insert the new element and heapify.

> Hence Worst Case Time - O( (n-k+1)*k ) + O(k) Space - O(k)

Can we do it better?

Comment: Probably this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11044634/1400768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do better if in the algorithm from OP we change expensive "heapify" procedure to much cheaper "upheap" or "downheap". This gives O(n * log(k)) time complexity.

Or, if we iterate through input array and put each element to the min-queue of size 'k', we can do it in O(n) time. Min-queue is a queue that can perform find-min in O(1) time. It may be implemented as a pair of min-stacks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7134189/1009831) for details.

Comment: But at the time of deletion we have to search for the element hence would be O(k) not log(k) here.
That's why i stated the worst case complexity would be O( (n-k+1)*k ) + O(k)

Comment: @Luv: there is no need to search for deleted element if we keep track of each heap element's position.